# React native iOS deep linking; how can I use `@` character in url

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking

I implemented deep linking to our project, and it is working.

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);

Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
  this._handleDeepLink(url);
});
```

but in here url coming without `@` character. I mean; I am clicking to `xxxx://@yyyyy` link, but it is getting like `xxxx://yyyyy`. But if i put @ second or other words, it is working as expected.

```
xxxx://@yyyyy => xxxx://yyyyy

xxxx://yyyyy/@zzzzz => xxxx://yyyyy/@zzzzz

xxxx://@yyyyy/@zzzzz => xxxx://yyyyy/@zzzzz
```

Also Android side has not this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the strings using `+` by checking a condition by using string check methods to check whether the `@` exists or not. IF not then concatenate